# SECR occasion column via R: how to give a number for each date in a sequence, but skip a number if a certain date isn't in that column?

Tags: r, date

I am trying to format my data for the spatially-explicit capture-recapture model (secr), for which we need an occasion column. I am taking a 90-day period of the overall data set per each year, with each row being a separate record of an animal on one of camera traps. Let's say that the first day is Feb 1st, 2019. It should get '1' in the 'occasion' column. The last day, May 1st, should get '90' in that column.

However, here's a catch: there wasn't a capture on every date of that time period, and some days there were multiple captures. So, the dates in the 'dt' column may go like this:

1. 2019-02-01
2. 2019-02-04
3. 2019-02-05
4. 2019-02-06
5. 2019-02-07
6. 2019-02-07
7. 2019-02-07

I want to create an 'occasion' column so that my final table could have columns like this:

1. 2019-02-01 | 1
2. 2019-02-04 | 4
3. 2019-02-05 | 5
4. 2019-02-06 | 6
5. 2019-02-07 | 7
6. 2019-02-07 | 7
7. 2019-02-07 | 7

I have gone two ways about this but neither was succesfull. Firstly, I tried this:

```
    data_new = data_old %>% 
               arrange(dt) %>% 
               mutate(occasion = as.numeric(factor(dt))
```

Which gave me the the table that looked like this:

1. 2019-02-01 | 1
2. 2019-02-04 | 2
3. 2019-02-05 | 3
4. 2019-02-06 | 4
5. 2019-02-07 | 5
6. 2019-02-07 | 5
7. 2019-02-07 | 5

So, the numbers for identical dates were identical, just how I wanted, but it didn't skip the number if the corresponding date was missing. I tried something more complicated:

First, I got the start dates for each of the 90-day periods per year.

```
    mydttemp <- as.POSIXct("2014-02-01")
    mydates = seq.POSIXt(from = mydttemp, length.out = 7, by = "1 year")
```

The final product for the list 'mydates' looked like this:

`

```
"2014-02-01 +11" 
"2015-02-01 +10" 
"2016-02-01 +10" 
"2017-02-01 +10" 
"2018-02-01 +10" 
"2019-02-01 +10" 
"2020-02-01 +10"
```

`

Second, I made the 90-day period for each year. I use a loop and the object fileNumber that goes through each year in the list (hence, the `mydates[fileNumber]` expression).

```
    mydate = seq.POSIXt(from = mydates[fileNumber], length.out = 90, by = "1 day")
    mydateseq = seq(as.character(mydate))
```

Finally, I feed these into the same part of my code, and it looks like this:

```
    for (m in mydateseq) {
       data_new = data_old %>% 
          arrange(dt) %>% 
          mutate(occasion = if_else(dt %in% mydate, 
                                    true = mydateseq[m], 
                                    false = NA_real_)
    }
```

The idea was that if a date matched any of the dates in the 'dt' column was found in the created list, it would put the corresponding number for that date into a column. But that just gave me a column full of NAs. Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Subtract the first date from the dates and add 1:

```
# test data
s <- c("2019-02-01", "2019-02-04", "2019-02-05", "2019-02-06", 
   "2019-02-07", "2019-02-07", "2019-02-07")

d <- as.Date(s)
as.integer(d - d[1] + 1L)
## [1] 1 4 5 6 7 7 7
```

Comment: Hi, I believe this only solves the issue in the example but not the entire question, unfortunately.